# Como utilizar dados de uma consulta no mongoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, pdf

Quero utilizar os dados que retornarem do 'find()' do MongoDB para, através de um forEach, criar uma tabela utilizando o array que retornar do MongoDB, e após a tabela pronta, gerar um PDF, porém não estou conseguindo ter acesso aos dados do result fora da função de conexão com o DB.

```
   db.open( function (err, mongoclient) {
    mongoclient.collection('postagens', function (err, collection) {
        collection.find().toArray(function(err, results){
            if(err){
                res.json(err);
            } else {
                res.send(results);
            }
            mongoclient.close();
            return results
        })

    })
})

let conteudoPDF = {
    content:[
        {text: 'Teste de PDF', style: 'header'},
        'Teste com pdfMake',
        {
            table:{
                body:[
                    [ 'Id Usuário', 'Id Post', 'Título', 'Texto'],
                   /*Aqui irá o forEach para gerar a tabela*/

                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

A variável 'results' contem o array com o JSON que preciso, e quero ter acesso à esses dados fora da função de conexão com o DB, e o 'return' não está exportando esses dados para fora da função

Comment: Indiquei como duplicada porquê o problema é o mesmo, só muda a forma de aplicar, quem olhar aqui poderá ver mais explicações nas outras respostas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode preencher o conteúdo do PDF invocando uma função para isso no *callback* de sucesso da consulta, dessa forma:

```
 db.open(function(err, mongoclient) {
    mongoclient.collection('postagens', function(err, collection) {
        collection.find().toArray(function(err, results) {
            if (err) {
                res.json(err);
            } else {
                // invocar a função que preenche o pdf aqui
                preencherPDF(results);
                res.send(results);
            }
            mongoclient.close();
            return results
        })

    })
})

function preencherPDF(conteudo) {
    let conteudoPDF = {
        content: [{
                text: 'Teste de PDF',
                style: 'header'
            },
            'Teste com pdfMake',
            {
                table: {
                    body: [
                        ['Id Usuário', 'Id Post', 'Título', 'Texto'],
                        /*Aqui irá o forEach para gerar a tabela*/
                        conteudo.forEach((item) => {
                            console.log(item)
                        });
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Vou testar aqui e já informo o resultado...

Comment: Se `let conteudoPDF` precisar ser lido fora do escopo da função, declare fora @LeonardoEbert

Comment: Tudo funcionou perfeitamente do jeito que você fez o código, o problema agora será adaptar o JSON para a estrutura da biblioteca pdfMake, mas agradeço muito a sua ajuda, sou iniciante em programação web e já estava com esse mesmo problema há 2 dias, muito obrigado.

Comment: De nada @LeonardoEbert. Caso precise de ajuda para adaptar o JSON nos será um prazer em uma nova pergunta =]

Comment: Pois é, esbarrei nessa dificuldade agora...

Comment: Já fiz uma nova pergunta