# Como adaptar um JSON para criar uma tabela no pdfMake?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, pdf

Preciso pegar um JSON que retorna do MongoDB e através de um forEach gerar uma tabela e criar um PDF, porém não estou conseguindo adaptar o JSON para a estrutura do pdfMake, segue trecho do JSON:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5978e9f71277a5dae49db945"),
    "userNumId" : 1,
    "numId" : 1,
    "titulo" : "sunt aut facere repellat provnumIdent occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "texto" : "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
}
```

Esse é apenas um documento do JSON, peguei os dados no site JSONPlaceholder e salvei no MongoDB, e agora não consigo adaptar para a estrutura do pdfMake.
Preciso que retorne todas as chaves, inclusive a "_id", pois quero imprimir todas as 5 na tabela. Desde já, agradeço.

Comment: Leonardo coloque nessa questão o trecho de `preencherPDF` tb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aproveitando a estrutura da sua [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/224509/como-utilizar-dados-de-uma-consulta-no-mongodb/224513#224513), se eu compreendi o [formato](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake#tables) poderia fazer dessa forma:

```
function preencherPDF(conteudo) {

    let corpo = [
        ['Id Usuário', 'Id Post', 'Título', 'Texto']
    ];
    conteudo.forEach((item) => corpo.push([item._id.toString(), item.numId, item.titulo, item.texto]));

    let conteudoPDF = {
        content: [{
                text: 'Teste de PDF',
                style: 'header'
            },
            'Teste com pdfMake',
            {
                table: {
                    body: corpo
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Cara, deu um errinho aqui com a estrutura do _id, mas creio que seja tranquilo pra resolver, nem sei como te agradecer...

Comment: Verdade, o `_id` vem formato ObjectId, editei a resposta @LeonardoEbert.

Comment: Muito obrigado mesmo Lucas, eu já estava nesse problema há dois dias, e não sabia mais o que fazer.

Comment: Funcionou 100%, nem sei como agradecer...